# Different use Transaction and use add to Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What's the difference when we use add data to firestore and use Transaction? I still don't understand this use. because he produces the same value. thanks

Comment: A transaction is only needed when you have multiple documents to change, and those changes must all be made at the same time, all in sync with each other.  A single document add with a unique ID doesn't need a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In one word I'll say we do this to beware from Race Condition.

**What is a Race Condition?**

A race condition is an undesirable situation that occurs when a device or system attempts to perform two or more operations at the same time, but because of the nature of the device or system, the operations must be done in the proper sequence to be done correctly

**Let me give you an example**

Suppose you are activating the user account.

To activate the user account you will go to the database and flip the value (`false` to `true`). At that same time, some else is also trying to activate the account they will also flip the value ( `true` to `false`).

Just to beware from these kinds of thing we use transition. Before performing any change in the database we read the data and confirm.

If you did not satisfy from my answer then do read about `Race Condition` because that is the exact answer.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, Sir. Your answer is very meaningful for my project!